# ASP.net/Vb.net page "permissions" -- How to make a page only accessible with valid Pin number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.net web page that should *only* be accessible should the user enter a valid Pin number on the welcome page.  They shouldn't be able to simply access the page by typing in the URL in their browser, for example.

```
Flow: User visits web page.  User enters their Pin on the welcome page. 
If Pin is valid, user is redirected to the page in question.
If Pin is invalid, show an error message stating that the Pin is invalid.
```

Okay, right now I have it set up so that they are redirected to the page if the Pin they enter is correct.  Problem is, this doesn't negate them from being able to enter the URL in their browser or otherwise access the page.  Of course, I could make the URL long and obfuscated, but this doesn't seem to me secure.

I have a lot of ideas of how to make the page secure.  The best example, is creating an obfuscated unique URL based off of their Pin, that redirects to the page in question, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this within the ASP.net realm.  It seems like there are methods, properties, or just in general coding techniques that should be built in to .net which handle this, since it is so common.  I just don't know about them, personally.

Also, I would like to make the connection to this page secure, perhaps using Https or some other security method.  Maybe this is best left to another question.

Comment: No. Obfuscation is not security. Instead, use existing tools that are designed to handle this, such as [Identity](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/). By the way, I really hope you're not using just a pin number. That'd be really easy to brute force attack.

Comment: No it's not just a Pin number, that is just an example.  This is all just an example, a framework for what I'm trying to get at here. Which is page permissions, and making certain pages unavailable.

Comment: Redirect the user during the Session Start event. Afterwards on pageloads check the session to assure the user has access and redirect as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to sound harsh here but what you want to accomplish, should be based on proper security. I would start with these tutorials and make my way from there http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

In short you could contain and restrict the user by logging onto the site, database security etc. This would give you further control and allow future updates and or add additional security methods if required.

Hope this helps